# What does "I never stopped to think of it" mean?

Tags: negation

I saw what I thought was a double negative in this sentence from *Norwegian Wood*

> I never stopped to think of it as something that would make a lasting impression.

The double negative in this sentence really confuses me. I interpret it as "I'm keeping to think of it as something that would make a lasting impression", but I feel like it should be interpreted as "I didn't think of it as something that would make a lasting impression until recently.", but I don't know how it can be interpreted in grammar to the latter version.

The first negative is, of course, ‘never’ - and I thought ‘stopped’ is the second negation. This is how I was thinking about it:

> I never think → I haven't thought
> I stopped to think → I didn't think

So

> I never stopped to think → I was and still am thinking

And now I am confusing myself.

Comment: So the former version is correct? But I think the latter version makes more sense to me. @User40475

Comment: Maybe I was wrong, I thought `never stopped to think` is the double negation. It confused me a lot.

Comment: Personally, I think the cited used is rather strange - even more so after having a quick look at the *context*. Apparently the writer is recalling a relaxing time spent ambling through a meadow with a childhood sweetheart, a long time ago. But I see no mention of any ***hasty action*** that would normally be associated with ***not stopping** to think*. I can't for the life of me understand why Haruki Murakami didn't write ***I never imagined it would be** something that would...* (surely not because he's not a native Anglophone? :)

Comment: (...and are we to understand ***until recently*** there as meaning ***I recently stopped to think** [differently about that past experience]?* Stopped doing ***what***, in order to have that thought?)

Comment: I admit I haven't seen the context, but maybe he's thinking along the lines of "I never paused (while we were ambling) to think what this could mean to me in the future" and it's only now he wishes he had? I agree that "never stopped" is usually hastier.

Comment: So far as I'm concerned, ***I never imagined X*** and ***X never occurred to me...*** are standard ways of indicating that some thought X ***never crossed my mind*** (often, because X ***wasn't*** an "obvious, natural" thing to think, at the time). But saying ***I never stopped to think X*** implies that I ***would*** have thought X, ***if I hadn't been in such a hurry*** (where oftentimes X would have been a relatively obvious thing to realise, but in my haste I overlooked it).

Comment: "Stopped to think" is almost idiomatic -> *"I stopped [doing everything else] for the purpose of concentrating on thinking"*.

Comment: The confusion is that "stopped" here means "paused" (eg. stopped moving), not "ceased"

Comment: @FumbleFingers: In normal idiomatic use, the "what" is usually understood to be some variation of "mindlessly going about my regular daily routine." The idiom implies that the speaker was so busy living their life, that they failed to consider [something].

Comment: Does it help your undertsanding if you replace `stopped to think of` with `considered` ?

Comment: The point that several answers have not made explicit is that _stop_ can only take an _-ing_  clause, and never an infinitive clause. There is no logic or rule to this: it is just a property that the verb _stop_ has. This means that if it is followed by a _to_ clause, that cannot be the complement of _stop_, but must have another meaning: most obviously a purpose clause.

Comment: @User40475 it means exactly the opposite. X never thought Y would leave a lasting impression.

Comment: @User40475: No, it means "never thought". It's the same as saying "I never took the time to think (this thought)."

Comment: Yes, you are confusing yourself, most obviously because there is no double negative. Here, ‘stopped’ is no more a negative than ’started’ would be. “I never think” could so rarely mean “I haven't thought” that you should drop it. I never think” has no place in English. “I could/should/would never think” work, but they are different. “I stopped to think” and “I didn't think” are near opposites. “I stopped to think” is not related to “I stopped thinking” “I stopped to think” always means “I (paused and) took time to think…” not comparable to “I didn't think."

Answer (score 38, accepted):

There is a difference between

> I [never] stopped to think

and

> I [never] stopped thinking

In the second, thinking is the object, it's the thing that does (or doesn't) get stopped.  The negation in the sentence "I never stopped thinking of it in this way" resolves to "I thought of it in this way and I continue thinking of it just the same."

In the first, we don't have an object.  We have an intention or a purpose.  Without an object, this verb is ergative or labile or unaccusative -- whatever label you prefer for the kind of verb that, in another language, uses the middle voice.  It's not the thinking that is stopped; it's *me* that stops.

So, "I never stopped to think" means that I never paused for that purpose, I never took the time to do that bit of thinking.  I was too busy for the idea to even occur to me.

In another sentence and especially with another verb, an infinitive like this *can* be an object.  If I say "I want to help", then "to help" does act as an object, and it is the *thing that I want*.

It doesn't seem that you're confused about the negation.  You're confused about the role of the phrasing "to think of it as...".  You're interpreting it as a direct object of a transitive "stopped".  The writer intends that you interpret it as *an adjunct of purpose or reason,* and to interpret "stopped" as an *intrasitive* and *unaccusative* usage of the verb.

Under that interpretation, "never stopped to think" means something close to "never took the time to have the idea".

Comment: `I [never] stopped to think` is grammatically similar, I think, to `I [never] stopped at that stop sign.`

Comment: Or,
I stopped [in order] to buy coffee.  
I stopped [in order] to think.  
I never stopped [in order] to think.

Comment: @Gary Botnovcan: Wonderful answer! Just a little doubt remains,  though; or maybe it's the whole point of the question,after all. I dont know. We know that infinitives and gerunds are interchangeable in most cases: _I like [swimming_]; _I like [to swim_], etc. Why doesn't this rule apply here as well? Is this because the verb happens to be *stopped* in this case?

Comment: @User40475 Gerunds and infinitives are not generally interchangeable in my mind as a native speaker--they are in some situations such as the one you described, but there are numerous situations like this (and any case with *stop*, as far as I can think of) where they aren't. I can't speak for all native speakers, but I've never really thought of them as interchangeable at least.

Answer (score 14):

As the other answers have said this isn't a double negative.

Your confusion seems to come from the interpretation of the phrase "stopped to think" which has a very different meaning from "stopped thinking". "stopped to x" means you paused in order to start to do x. "Stopped x" means you ceased to do x

A different way to write this sentence with the same meaning would be

> I have never paused in order to think of it as...

This is also grammatically correct and has nearly the same meaning

> I have never thought of it as...

The difference is very subtle. The first sentence implies that if the speaker had taken the time to pause and think about the topic they would have come to a different conclusion. The second sentence simply states that they have never had this thought.

If you wanted to write a sentence with the meaning you are thinking of " I was and still am thinking" you could say

> I have never stopped thinking of it as...

If you wanted to write something that means "I'm keeping to think of it as something that would make a lasting impression" you could say

> I have always thought of it as...

or

> I always think of it as...

If you wanted to write sentences you gave as examples these would be their meanings:

> I never think (about xyz) → In the present I do not [ever] think (about xyz)

> I haven't thought (about xyz) → In the past I have not [ever] thought (about xyz)

> I stopped to think (about xyz) → I paused what I was doing and then thought (about xyz)

> I didn't think (about xyz) → I failed to consider (xyz) in the past (This implies I should have thought about something)

Answer (score 8):

It isn't a double negative. "Never" is the only negation.

> I never stopped to think

is a fairly common idiom. It means "I didn't take the time to think".

The sentence could be re-written as "If I'd thought about it (but I didn't), I might have realised that it could make a lasting impression".

You can use the same construction in a positive way as well.

> When you stop to think about it, tadpoles turning into frogs is pretty weird.

Answer (score 4):

It's kind of a short way to say:

> I never stopped [everything else I was doing] to think [about this particular topic].

meaning... "I was vaguely aware of something but never spent the time to consider it fully."